# Checkbox is checked when Workorder has attachment(from workorder application)

Tags: websphere, maximo

I have a requirement to create a checkbox in Maximo and the checkbox will get checked automatically, if that wo has any attachment attached it. How do I do this?

Is it possible to do it through Condition expression or through automation script only?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing relationship between workorder and doclinks.
If you don't give users the ability to set "getlatestversion" on doclinks,
you can put a checkbox on your presentation with `DOCLINKS.GETLATESTVERSION` for the attribute.